# Pausing a simple slider on action | setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, setinterval

Could someone please help me add a pause and resume on hover with the following slideshow?

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow >img:first')
  .hide()
  .next()
  .show()
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  2000);
```

If it helps I have a working codepen link as well. You will see another image, that I am using the same setInterval function to change the image id. Ideally, this pause function would stop both setInterval loops. But if I could get some help with this example, I may be able to retrofit the rest.

http://codepen.io/banunn/pen/EKfuj

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post the working `codepan` link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the id returned by setInterval to a variable, so that you can call clearInterval on hover. For example,

```
function startInterval(){
   return setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow >img:first')
      .hide()
      .next()
      .show()
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
      },  2000);
    }
    var int= startInterval();

    $('#slideshow').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(int);
    },function(){
        int = startInterval();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create two functions to start and "stop" the slider, and when it stops you save the slide position to restart from that point after like this:

```
var interval, position;

function runSlide(position) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow >img:first').eq(position)
            .hide()
            .next()
            .show()
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        position = $('#slideshow > img:visible').index();
    }, 2000);
}

function stopSlide(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

[Here is a PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myBtA) with the example.

**But how does it save the slider position if you don't used anything to identify them?**

Simple, young padawan, it simply get the `img` from slideshow which is `:visible` and assumes that this `img` is the right point to start slider again.